# How to separate normal text from the frame block?

Tags: org-export, latex, beamer

I just want to make the text appear separate from the above frame box in beamer export `C-c C-e l O` as in the MWE below.

MWE:

```
#+TITLE: Frame or Text?
#+AUTHOR: Casual Author
#+DATE:
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:t num:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport


#+BEAMER_THEME: default
#+BEAMER_COLOR_THEME: seagull
#+BEAMER_OUTER_THEME: default
#+BEAMER_INNER_THEME: rectangles
#+BEAMER_FONT_THEME: structurebold


#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col) %8BEAMER_OPT(Opt)


* Section
** Introduction
Some text is flowing here.
*** Definition
    This is a general statement that should be appearing within a frame, but is should be separate from the two coming points below.

    1. first point
    2. second point
```

**Output**

[image]

**Question**

How to make the two points appear outside the frame box exactly as in the `Some text is flowing here`. Leaving two empty lines before the numbered list did not solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the structure of org-mode documents. The stuff from a head line up to a head line of at least the same level belongs to the heading. ([See the worg-documentation of org-mode syntax.](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html))

Try to exploit that structure!

For an example introduce a level-3 headline after the definition and before the list. That headline can even be empty!
That puts the list into its own box.

```org
#+TITLE: Frame or Text?
#+AUTHOR: Casual Author
#+DATE:
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:t num:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport


#+BEAMER_THEME: default
#+BEAMER_COLOR_THEME: seagull
#+BEAMER_OUTER_THEME: default
#+BEAMER_INNER_THEME: rectangles
#+BEAMER_FONT_THEME: structurebold


#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col) %8BEAMER_OPT(Opt)


* Section
** Introduction
Some text is flowing here.

*** Definition
    This is a general statement that should be appearing within a frame, but is should be separate from the two coming points below.

*** 

  1. first point
  2. second point
```

[image: Separation of blocks with empty header line]

---

An **alternative approach** is to use the [org special block `definition`](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-special-blocks.html) for the definition. The definition is set like a sub-heading into a box with title bar:

```org
#+TITLE: Frame or Text?
#+AUTHOR: Casual Author
#+DATE:
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:t num:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport


#+BEAMER_THEME: default
#+BEAMER_COLOR_THEME: seagull
#+BEAMER_OUTER_THEME: default
#+BEAMER_INNER_THEME: rectangles
#+BEAMER_FONT_THEME: structurebold


#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col) %8BEAMER_OPT(Opt)


* Section
** Introduction
   Some text is flowing here.

#+begin_definition
This is a general statement that should be appearing within a frame, but is should be separate from the two coming points below.
#+end_definition

     1. first point
     2. second point
```

[image: Using org special block for the header line]

Comment: good, but going back to the plain text without any box as in `Some text is flowing ...`, seems to be not possible, which is a shame.

Comment: @doctorate No it is not a shame. The main objective of org-mode is organizing things and not making presentations. It is **not** just a markdown language. If you want to use orgmode for your distinct purposes you need to understand orgmode's tree structure and you need to decide whether your distinct purpose fits into that structure. (IMHO)

Comment: Org-mode is growing up everyday in all directions. Who knows? may be someone would come up with an answer in the future. Let us wait.

Comment: @doctorate I've added an alternative approach.

Comment: I didn't know that such an org block exists. when I do `#+begin_` and hit pcomplete `C-M-i`, `_definition` won't show up in the completion list . So how can one find such org block documented in emacs? That solves the question *only if* it is a definition. Had it been other word like `XYZ` it won't work I guess.

Comment: @doctorate I've linked the doc of special blocks in the answer. Special blocks are now part of vanilla orgmode.

Comment: @doctorate Just export it as beamer as you already have done it.